# UITableView appears with empty cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a problem displaying `UITableView`: Some cells are empty, and content in cells becomes visible only after scrolling (if empty cell scrolls out of the screen and then goes back). I Can't understand what might be the problem.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateFilesList];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    animated = YES;
    [self updateFilesList];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.filesList retain];

    NSString *title = [self.filesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    title = [title stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    title = [title lastPathComponent];
    if (title.length >33) {
        title = [title substringFromIndex:33];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_png-1.png"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have the cell customization code that happens before you create the cell.

Change it like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.filesList retain];

    NSString *title = [self.filesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    title = [title stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    title = [title lastPathComponent];
    if (title.length >33) {
        title = [title substringFromIndex:33];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // This part creates the cell for the firs time
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // This part customizes the cells
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_png-1.png"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you make

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_png-1.png"]];
cell.textLabel.text = title;
```

before

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

change the order. What is happening is that the first time you execute the table View you never do the title before the alloc. When you reuse cell it works because the cell != nil

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! You are right, that is the problem! All guys posted working answer, so I will accept only the first one

Comment: OK thanks. Think always that you don't have for sure a valid cell after alloc it. When you reuse a cell it could return you nil in case he don't find any usable cell, that happens for sure at first show of the table. When you have problems related with refresh or other stuff like that observe that part of your code. For sure you will find the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put these lines

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_png-1.png"]];
cell.textLabel.text = title;
```

after the `if(){...}` condition.

In the first pass cells are nil. Put those lines before the `if` does nothing. This is why you see empty cells.

*A simple question*

Why do you call `[self.filesList retain]` ?

Hope it helps.